# PCC as covariance of z-score scaled variables and weights incorporation

Tags: pearson-r, weights, z-score

I've usually seen the Pearson Correlation Coefficient as :
$$ 
\text{PCC}(u,v) = 
\frac{
    \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
        (r_{ui} - \mu_u)(r_{vi} - \mu_v)
    }
}
{
    \sqrt{
        \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
            (r_{ui} - \mu_u)^2
        }
        \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
            (r_{vi} - \mu_v)^2
        }
    }
}
$$
Recently I was looking into the fact that in certain scenarios it could be beneficial to weight the PCC with regards to variance but the paper I was reading used a different formulation of the PCC.

The paper interpreted the PCC as the covariance of two vectors that have been scaled to z-scores [1, sec. 5.3] thus using the following formula :
$$
PCC(u,v) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}{z_{ui} z_{vi}}}{m}
$$
and followed by incorporating a variance weight term $f_i$ as :
$$
WPCC(u,v) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{m}{f_iz_{ui} z_{vi}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{m}{f_i}}
$$ 
I was looking into incorporating the variance weight term in the first formulation of the PCC, could someone please point me or provide a derivation of the first formula from the second one or viceversa?
Thanks in advance!

Refs : [1] : http://files.grouplens.org/papers/algs.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the weighted mean is:
$$
\mu = \frac{\sum_i f_i x_i}{\sum_i f_i}
$$

And the population weighted variance is:
$$
\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_i f_i (x_i-\mu)^2}{\sum_i f_i}
$$

The unweighted values of the mean and the variance are obtained by having $f_i=1$.

The $z$-score is:
$$
z_i = \frac{x_i-\mu}{\sigma}
$$
Which transforms the variable $X$ in a variable $Z$ with mean $0$ and variation $1$.

So, incorporating the weights $f_i$ in the first formula, we get:
$$ 
\text{WPCC}(u,v) = 
\frac{
    \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
        f_i (r_{ui} - \mu_u)(r_{vi} - \mu_v)
    }
}
{
    \sqrt{
        \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
            f_i (r_{ui} - \mu_u)^2
        }
        \sum_{i \in I_u \cap I_v}{
            f_i (r_{vi} - \mu_v)^2
        }
    }
}
$$

---

**Edit:**

Working from your 2nd PCC formula:
$$
PCC(u,v) = \frac{\sum_i z_{ui} z_{vi}}{m}
$$

Replacing the $z$-scores, we get:
$$
PCC(u,v) = \frac{\sum_i 
\frac{r_{ui}-\mu_{u}}{\sigma_{u}}
\cdot
\frac{r_{vi}-\mu_{v}}{\sigma_{v}}
}{m}
$$

I.e.,
$$
PCC(u,v) = \frac{
\sum_i 
(r_{ui}-\mu_{u})
(r_{vi}-\mu_{v})
}{m \sigma_{u} \sigma_{v}}
$$

Expanding the unweighted variance formula, we get:
$$
PCC(u,v) = \frac{
\sum_i 
(r_{ui}-\mu_{u})
(r_{vi}-\mu_{v})
}{\sqrt{m^2 
\frac{\sum_i (r_{ui}-\mu_{u})^2}{m}
\cdot
\frac{\sum_i (r_{vi}-\mu_{v})^2}{m}
}}
$$

And simplifying the $m$ terms, we get the 1st PCC formula.

Comment: I'm unsure where the $m$ factors at the denominator ends up. According to this I have $\frac{ \sum{(\frac{x_{ui} - \mu_u}{\sigma_u})(\frac{x_{vi} - \mu_v}{\sigma_v})}}{m}$ after some reductions I get $\frac{\frac{\sum{(x_{ui} - \mu_u)(x_{vi} - \mu_v)}}{\sigma_u \sigma_v}}{m}$ which is different from the PCC formula, I guess I'm doin something wrong, could you provide a hint in your answer as to this please?

Comment: @LucaGrignani : I've edited my post to include an answer to your question in the comment above.

Comment: Thanks a lot, completely forgot the $m$ term in the std. dev. formula :D Have a good one and thanks again!